# Kotlin: Group a List into a Map of Maps

Tags: list, dictionary, lambda, collections, kotlin

How to group list into map of maps using lambdas? Imperative solution looks following:

```
private class Data(val a: Int, val b: Int, val c: Int)

@JvmStatic
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val dataList = listOf(Data(1, 2, 3), Data(4, 5, 6), Data(7, 8, 9), Data(1, 10, 11))
    val result = mutableMapOf<Int, MutableMap<Int, Int>>()
    for (data in dataList) {
        val aMap = result.getOrPut(data.a) { mutableMapOf() }
        aMap[data.b] = data.c
    }
    println(result)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
dataList.groupBy { it.a }
        .mapValues { (_, v) -> v.associate { it.b to it.c } }
```

The `groupBy` function creates a `Map<Int, List<Data>>`, where the `List<Data>` is all data-objects that shares the same value in `a`. Then I map the values of the `Map`, creating the structure you needed.

Comment: You could replace `.map { xxx }.toMap()` with `.associate { xxx }` to avoid the intermediate weird temporary list of pairs.

Comment: @Kiskae Ah, that's it. I was looking for that function, but couldn't find it.

Comment: I'm using this `dataList.groupBy { it.a }.mapValues { (_, v) -> v.associateBy({ it.b }, { it.c }) }`